# Why does releasing a view controller cause a crash?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, release, exc-bad-access

I always push a new view controller onto the stack like this:

```
 MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

[vc release];
```

And all works well when it comes to popping it off the stack with:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

But now when I pop the vc off the stack I get a crash in main.m stating a bad access at line:`int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`

But now if I comment out [vc release] no more crash?

But why and surely this leaks memory as Im not releasing something I created?

Comment: Did you try running it in debug mode? Find out the exact line at which it crashes. Maybe this has nothing to do with the release at all since the code you posted seems to be correct

Comment: Posting the detailed message from your console, and if you don't mind, the code for MyViewController, might help.

Comment: Please post the backtrace. The crash is not at that line; it's at some line of assembler about 20 stack frames further down. The code you posted is fine, so you did something wrong somewhere else that did something inappropriate to the reference count of the view controller or one of the objects it decrements, most likely one it decrements during `-dealloc` or `-viewDidUnload`. The backtrace should tell you exactly what sort of object you did something wrong with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your memory management looks fine.  Perhaps you are mismanaging the memory of something inside of your vc.  What does the dealloc method of MyViewController look like?

My guess is you are using the incorrect init method (perhaps initWithNibName:bundle:) and you are releasing ivars in dealloc that were never properly initialized.

Comment: So I used initWithNibName and no more crash!  This is a new one on me as I have ALWAYS used init regardless of IB or manual creation.  This still leaves me a little in the dark...   I marked this post up and as the answer although other also said same, I dont think I am allowed to flag more than one post as the answer?  Thanks to you all for your input and pointing me to my flaw!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using it as a

```
@property
```

Comment: use @property (nonatomic, retain)

Comment: No I dont think making this view controller a property would help. I have a feeling this crash has something to do with code that he hasn't posted......

Answer (score 0):

Navigation controller will retain `vc` then, when `vc` is popped, `navigationController` releases it and `vc` deallocs.

So, you must leave the release code, it is correct.

I think you have to use a `initWithNibName:bundle:` insted of the `init`.

Comment: No I think he is correct in calling the release after pushing the VC. And you should use initWithNibName if you're using IB to build the VC otherwise init is fine.

Comment: I just said that he must call the release after pushing the VC :)
For the initWithNibName it may be my fault.

Comment: Oh lol sorry my bad I thought you were telling him to not release it..... This is what lack of coffee does to me!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why they are different is that you are not allocating the text objects, and therefore you are not the owner. It is the IB's job to alloc and realese them, which it does.

So if you also try to release it, it will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps you are mismanaging the memory of something inside of your vc.

This sentence from @brandontreb really helped me! I've struggled a whole day to fix the crash after a 'Received simulated memory warning', exactly descripted like:
[Preventing bad access crash for popViewControllerAnimated in uinavigationcontroller setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5528508/790198)

In my pushed view controller's loadView:, passed the view controller self to its dataSource's init:.

```
LayoutPickerDataSource *pickerDataSource = [[LayoutPickerDataSource alloc] initWithController:self];
```

while the dataSource class retained it like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) LayoutViewController *viewController;
```

Fix the crash just change to:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) LayoutViewController *viewController;
```

and remove:

```
[viewController release];
```

bingo! I still don't know why! As viewController released in dealloc: of dataSource.